# How to implode with eol in php?

Tags: php, implode

As the title says.. how can I implode an array of strings and seperate them with a new line?
Ive tried

```
implode(";\n", $my_array);
```

and

```
implode(";".PHP_EOL, $my_array);
```

thanks

edit: should have added that im writing to .txt file and theyre not showing up when viewed in notepad

```
file_put_contents($my_path, implode(";\n", $my_array));
```

**ok there are line breaks when i open it in notepad++ so it did work all along, thanks**

Comment: Are you actually using the results of `implode()` at all? i.e. `$something = implode(...);`? Your code works just fine.

Comment: Your title pretty much spells out the code for you http://codepad.org/SuvHdhNd

Comment: if you're in a browser view, it'd have to be `";<br/>"`, because HTML doesn't honor line breaks except very specific circumstances. Plus, PHP_EOL is almost useless, especially when dealing with multiple platforms. PHP_EOL on your server is almost certainly not going to be the EOL char(s) on some other server. The only time you should use it if you're producing things to be consumed on the exact SAME platform type.

Comment: Are you looking at the HTML or the source code? HTML won't show the `\n` character, however it **does** show `<br />`.

Comment: im writing it to a .txt file and there are no line breaks

Comment: If you're on windows you need \r too. Use PHP_EOL instead of ;\n instead to account for both.

Comment: \r\n made it work in notepad where PHP_EOL didnt. so thats the answer i guess if you want to change that comment to an answer!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/plain");

$arr = ["one", "two", "three"];

echo implode(PHP_EOL, $arr);
```

Works well. If you're viewing in an HTML browser without specifying a content-type, try looking at the **View Source**.